# EKS, Windows node. networkPlugin cni failed, Failed to create pod sandbox

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am new in EKS and launching self-managed Windows nodes but my pod is stuck into  “ContainerCreating” status while creating POD on windows node.
I am following below steps to create it.

1. Managed nodes – Linux - Step 1 to Step 4 to create cluster with Linux (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html)
2. Deployed Linux workload to test (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sample-deployment.html). The Linux node is working properly.
3. Enabling windows Support (To enable Windows support for your cluster with a Windows client) (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/windows-support.html#enable-windows-support)
4. Launching self-managed Windows nodes (AWS Management Console) (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-windows-workers.html)
5. Deploy a Windows sample application(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/windows-support.html#windows-sample-application)
   While investigating (describing POD) I am getting below error.

   > Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox    pod/windows-server-iis-  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container  network for pod "windows-server-iis- ": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "windows-server-iis- _default" network: failed to parse Kubernetes args: pod does not have label vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address

Some more input.

1. I am using Freetier account.
2. I am using t3.Micro for Managed Node for Linus (along with Cluster) with 2 nodes – Step 4 in point 1
3. I am using 2.micro for Self self-managed Windows nodes with 2 instance node – in point 4 above.
4. Not creating any addition VPC/Security Group/ Role/ServiceAccount or IAM Policy other then given in above steps.
5. I can see POD with

   ```
   Limits:      vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address:  1
   Requests:      vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address:  1
   ```

Comment: Can you show your content in aws-auth ConfigMap? Run `kubectl get configmap aws-auth -n kube-system`

Comment: I am getting below values while running 
NAME       DATA   AGE
aws-auth   1      35m

Comment: While describing pod I am getting below details.
mapRoles:
--
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:role/myAmazonEKSNodeRole
  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
  groups:
    - system:bootstrappers
    - system:nodes
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:role/my-cluster-windows-nodegroup-NodeInstanceRole-<SomeID>
  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
  groups:
    - system:bootstrappers
    - system:nodes
    - eks:kube-proxy-windows

Comment: Can you provide VPC resource controller logs? And describe for the windows nodes?

Comment: Could you please guide how to get the logs